# Is a visa needed for a Thai national to visit Ukraine?

Tags: visas, ukraine, thai-citizens

I’m visiting Ukraine from England for around two weeks in October for a training course and a bit of sightseeing when I’m there.

My Thai friend still living in Thailand would like to join me, can she visit without a visa or do visa on arrival?

I’d like some concrete references as I keep finding conflicting info

Answer (score 1):

According to Timatic, the system used by airlines, to travel direct to Ukraine your friend should apply for an e-visa before travelling https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b

You’d need to check any transit visa requirements, depending on the flight routing.